# If $u\in H_{0}^{m}(\Omega)$ then $\|D^{m} f(u)\|_{2}<+\infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose that $u\in H_{0}^{m}(\Omega)$ and $f(u)=|u|^{p-2}u$, $(p\geq2)$. Is it possible to say $\|D^{m} f(u)\|_{2}<+\infty $, $(m\geq1)$?  My statement is correct for $m=1$ and $p=2$. It seems that it is also true for $m=1$ and $p>2$. But what happens when $m>1$ and $p>2$? ($\Omega$ is considered to be an open bounded domain in $R^{N}, N\geq 1$).

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be a ball with center on the origin and radius one. For $q<0$, try to characterize the values of $q$ for which your statement is true for the function $u(x)=\|x\|^q$.

Comment: Thanks. But, $u(x)=\|x\|^{q}\in H_{0}^{m}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Thank you again. I do know those relations if you mean the Sobolev exponents. But $u(x)=\|x\|^{q}|_{\partial\Omega}\neq 0$ if $\Omega$ is a ball with radius one and it is not differentiable (in weak sense) if $q<0$. Am I right?